# Reading a QR code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image-processing, qr-code

I downloaded `Refinery.Barcodes.Reader.dll`, and am using this:

```
Imports BusinessRefinery.Barcodes.Reader

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnread_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnread.Click
        Dim barcodes As String() = BarCodeReader.scanBarCode("D://QRSAMPLE.png", BusinessRefinery.Barcodes.Reader.BarCodeType.QRCODE)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It runs fine; no errors are thrown. But how do I see the result of the decoding process?

Comment: Doesn't `barcodes` contain what you want?

Comment: OMG :(  that was silly of me :\

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `myTextBox.Text = barcodes` before the `End Sub`.

*edit:*

After seeing comments, I think what you're running into is that scanBarCode returns an array, not a String.  Check that, and try something like this:

```
Imports BusinessRefinery.Barcodes.Reader

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnread_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnread.Click
        Dim barcodes As String() = BarCodeReader.scanBarCode("D://QRSAMPLE.png", BusinessRefinery.Barcodes.Reader.BarCodeType.QRCODE)
        myTextbox.Text = barcodes(0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: it tell me VALUE OF TYPE '1 DIMENSIONAL ARRAY' ....... cannot be converted to string ( barcodes is underlined blue ) ... what is that ?

Comment: Sounds like BarCodeReader.scanBarCode is returning an array, and you're trying to put it into a string.. I'll update my answer..

Comment: Man ... still wrong ... now it says barcodes[1] is not declared and may be inacessible due to protection level.  .... !!!!!

Comment: GOT IT ... man thnxxxx its your SQUARE BRACKETS that are wrong it shud be ()

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAA :@ ...... WHEN I CLICK THE BUTTON after running it i get .. ERROR : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: LOL SOLVED ....  myTextbox.Text = barcodes(0) .. solves it ;) THANK U VERY MUCH @techie007

Comment: pal do u hav something in asp.net( VB ) to be able to take a picture from a webcam and save it as png or jpg or bmp ina  folder ?